# LDAP server behind proxy

Tags: routing, proxy, ldap, haproxy

I am trying to set up LDAP server behind proxy.

I am using proxy because I have only one static IP address, but LDAP auth is bind to `ldap.mydomain.com`.

So I want to redirect all requests to LDAP server behind proxy.

I am using `HAProxy` and it supports TCP connections. But I have not found how can I set up it with LDAP.

Or it would be better to redirect only HTTP/HTTPS requests to the proxy and all other TCP requests redirect directly to the server with the help of my router configuration ?

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not plan to implement LDAP Balancing (and do not use HAProxy for other purposes too) - it is better to use port forwarding.

Nevertheless, here's [a good article with an example](http://ypbind.de/maus/ldap_ha_loadbalancing.html) of the use HAProxy TCP balancing for LDAP protocol.